# JRadioButton: how to replace text by IconImage?

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

I want to replace the text in my radio button list by an icon.

I've tried this:

```
rotateButton = new JRadioButton(rotateIcon.getImage());
```

But this replaces the radio button and text by the icon. I would like to keep the radio button and display the image.

What should I do?

---

What I'm currently getting is:

[image]

But I want it to end up with this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[public JRadioButton(String text, Icon icon)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JRadioButton.html#JRadioButton%28java.lang.String,%20javax.swing.Icon%29) and simple example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/CreatingJRadioButtonComponents.htm)

Comment: @Eng. Fouad: I also see him in most of Swing questions seems like mKorble is a swing enthusiast.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad because there are lots of fun, kind people with peaceFullFaces, and learning English language :-) that for me harder as any of PL as I know,

Comment: *"that for me harder as any of PL as I know.."*  Programming languages are a lot more *logical* than English.  ;)

Comment: Sorry but its not what I'm looking for, I want to keep the existing radio and replace the text by an image. as here is replaces the default radio button by the image and keeps the text

Comment: @Jason Rogers I'm not see any problem in that, what's your issue

Comment: Since I'm not being clear with words I did a paint work of whats my problem and added it in the edit

Comment: this answer is wrong, shouldn't be the accepted one. A correct answer is given by @andrew-thompson.

Answer (score 9):

Create a JRadioButton with no text and put a JLabel with the image next to it. You can also create a class to hide complexity.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class RadioButtonWithImage extends JPanel {

private JRadioButton radio = new JRadioButton();
private JLabel image;

public RadioButtonWithImage(Icon icon) {
    image = new  JLabel(icon);
    add(radio);
    add(image);
}

public void addToButtonGroup(ButtonGroup group) {
    group.add(radio);
}

public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
    radio.addActionListener(listener);
}

public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
    radio.addChangeListener(listener);
}

public Icon getImage() {
    return image.getIcon();
}

public void setImage(Icon icon) {
    image.setIcon(icon);
}

} // end class RadioButtonWithImage
```

Answer (score 5):

I just reproduced your described behavior using this source:

```
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.net.URL;

class RadioWithImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" +
            "a1ab0af4997654345d7a949877f8037e?s=128");
        Image image = ImageIO.read(url);
        final ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(image);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JRadioButton radioButton = new JRadioButton("A.T.", imageIcon);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, radioButton);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: Where is the radio button 'selected' icon?]

It seems like a bug to me, though I cannot recall seeing a radio with an icon.  How are they supposed to look?

---

Time to reach into my 'box of hacks'.

```
import javax.swing.*;

class RadioWithImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" +
            "a1ab0af4997654345d7a949877f8037e?s=128";
        final String html = "<html><body><img src='" +
            url +
            "' width=128 height=128>";
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JRadioButton radioButton = new JRadioButton(html);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, radioButton);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: Radio Button with Image]

This technique will not work if:

1. The use-case requires other types of icons (pressed, roll-over, selected etc.)
2. The button is disabled (it will render incorrectly).

Comment: looks like as Java6 forgot for that, but I think that you are here one of Htlm Gurus ... +1

Comment: @mKorbel  Oh no!  I may seem an HTML guru to Java programmers, but to the web-designers, I'm a newbie.  But thanks for saying it.  ;)  Yours was a good answer by the way, +1.  I like answers that include links to the latest JDocs. :)

Comment: I'm really confused how quickly can coding todays newbie

Answer (score 4):

There is no radio button constructor that allows an image as the content argument instead of a text. The only way to replace the text of a radio button by an image it is generate html and pass it as an argument to the default constructor.

```
import javax.swing.*;

class RadioWithImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = Windows_ChordsGenerator.class.getResource("/images/img1.png");

        final String html = "<html><body><img src='" + url.toString() +"'>";

        JRadioButton radioButton = new JRadioButton(html);     
       }
}
```

Comment: Great answer! This is more useful than @Andrew Thompson's answer because it uses an image actually bundled with the jar, and not an external resource.